# How do I load the dummy network adapter in linux if it's not as a module?

Tags: linux, vpn, kernel, ipsec

I want to build a roadwarrior ipsec gateway for routing traffic securely through my server.

For this, I plan to use racooon and debian linux. I have a VPS with a monolithic kernel (no kernel modules!), and since I need an internal NAT network for the VPn to work, I need some way to add a dummy interface to the kernel.

The question is, how can I see if dummy.ko is in the kernel built-in, and if it is, how can I activate it? modprobe dummy won't do. The VPS seems to be running under OpenVZ, and the kernel is from Redhat EL5. Is this impossible?

If there are other good solutions for accomplishing this roadwarrior setup, they'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ifconfig` to [bring it up](http://wiki.networksecuritytoolkit.org/nstwiki/index.php/Dummy_Interface).

Comment: ifconfig just notifies me of "No such device" - does this mean my kernel simply does not have dummy.ko, not built in nor as a module?

Comment: It is possible. Many VPS providers have their own kernel which may not include all desired options. You'll have to talk to your host.

Comment: Heh, in fact, I had already halfway written to my host before creating this question.

Answer (score 1):

> The VPS seems to be running under OpenVZ, and the kernel is from Redhat EL5. Is this impossible?

You'll need to contact the administrator, it needs to add a privilege for you to use the modules. A dummy module isn't the only thing you'll need access to, there are 4 or 5 modules needed to have a OpenVPN server running, IPsec may need more.